# El componente **Switch** no renderiza en React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, routes

Tengo el siguiente codigo y al ejecutarlo el componente **switch** no renderiza correctamente, solo funciona cuando esta comentado, no se cual es el problema ya que no me manda mensaje de error en la consola al ejecutar el **npm start**

Los unicos warnings que tengo son de eslint, pero solo eso, la pagina se muestra en local host pero no aparace el componente, solo cuando esta comentado el codigo de **switch**.

```
   import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import {BrowserRouter}  from 'react-router-dom';
    
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
       <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    
    );
```

y el archivo App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import AddReview from "./components/add-review"
import MoviesList from "./components/movies-list"
import Movie from "./components/movie"
import Login from "./components/login"
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  
  async function login(user = null){
    setUser(user)
  }

  async function logout(){
    setUser(null)
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand>Movies Reviews</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link>
              <Link to={"/movies"}>Movies</Link>
              </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link>
            { user ? (
              <a onClick={logout}>Logout User</a>
            ):(
              <Link to ={"/login"}>Login</Link> 
            )}
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        
     <Switch>
        <Route exact path={["/","/movies"]} component={MoviesList}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/movies/:id/review" render={(props)=>
         <AddReview {...props} user={user}/>
        }>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/movies/:id/" render={(props)=>
        <Movie {...props} user={user}/>
        }>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" render={(props)=>
        <Login {...props} login={login}/>
        }>
        </Route>
       </Switch> 
         
         </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Alguien ha pasado por este tipo de problemas?
Talves tenga que ver con el BrowserRouter, pero si lo elimino de la lista de import React no me reconoce Switch.

Comment: En vez de <Switch> prueba con <Routes>

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que estás usando la versión 5 de React Router. En ambos componentes estás usando `BrowserRouter`, sin embargo esto solo deberías usarlo en tu componente `Index` (el primero), en el segundo (App) donde manejas las diferentes rutas estás asignando un alias a BrowserRouter `BrowserRouter as Switch`, sin embargo deberías exportar `Switch` de React Router, sino solo estás implementando el mismo componente dos veces y seguro React se está quejando de eso.

En resumen, tus imports deberían de quedar así:

Index.tsx
`import {BrowserRouter}  from 'react-router-dom';`

App.tsx
`import { Switch } from "react-router";`

También por favor nota que Switch debería ser exportado de "react-router", mientras que BrowserRouter de 'react-router-dom', puedes ver más detalles en [la documentación](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/location-object)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.
E